# Is there a standard way to name a function which reads from a stream but does not advance the pointer?

Tags: naming-conventions

I can only think of Peek() and ReadNoAdvance() atm, but I wonder if there are better or standard options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

peek is the standard name, present in various languages.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen ReadAhead(), but I think Peek() is more standard.

Answer (score 1):

When writing parsers I've often also used `lookahead`.